# How do I fix force close issues due to a older version of Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a weather related app, and have come across an issue with compatibility. I have set up a "info" tab on the action bar to display a info.xml, but when using this on android 2.2/2.3 if produces a force close. Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Oh and P.S. my app is open source: https://github.com/bretth18/TemperatureConverter

Comment: Please post stacktrace. If compatibility, I think you may need to modify your code and find device android version then execute corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the AVD Manager that comes with the Android SDK, [**create new AVDs**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) that specifically target the versions of Android you are having issues with (try to be specific as possible, even down to the screen size).  You can then change your project to use that AVD on startup, or before debugging you can manually launch the emulator using the following command line.

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

Comment: I already have done that, i just cant really seem to find the issue to as why the layout will not load.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this, maybe it will help

```
public void addFragment(Fragment frag, boolean backstack) {
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction =        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.base, frag);

        if(backstack) {
            mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Support Package, see the link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html